# How to set initial value on md-select inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm sorry if this is already answered, but the behavior of angular's md-select is driving me to drink.

I have a situation where I'm creating an array of objects that contain some fields and a select element. I want to pre-select the values inside the select element, and I'm getting strange behaviour.

Here's the HTML (using angular material):

```
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="condition in conditions track by $index">
      <div layout="row" flex>
        <div flex="5">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div flex="25">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>From</label>
            <input required type="number" name="from" minvalue=0 maxvalue="100" ng-model="condition.from">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="5">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div flex="25">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>To</label>
            <input required type="number" name="to" minvalue=0 maxvalue="100" ng-model="condition.to">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="5">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div flex="25">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Select Question</label>
            <md-select ng-model="condition.question[$index]" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value._id'}" required name="cQuestion">
            <md-option ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy : '_id'" ng-selected="{{condition.question._id === question._id ? true : false}}" ng-value={{question}}>
              {{question.title}}
            </md-option>
            </md-select>               
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div flex="5">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
```

Here's the js that creates the values I'm trying to test for:

```
$scope.questions = [
  {title: 'Question 1', qtype: 1, _id:1},
  {title: 'Question 2', qtype: 2, _id:2},
  {title: 'Question 3', qtype: 3, _id:3},
  {title: 'Question 4', qtype: 4, _id:4},
  {title: 'Question 5', qtype: 5, _id:5}
];
$scope.conditions = [];
var condition = {};
condition.from = '';
condition.to ='';

condition.question = {title: 'Question 2', qtype: 2, _id:3};
$scope.conditions.push(condition);
 condition.from = '';
condition.to ='';

condition.question = {title: 'Question 5', qtype: 5, _id:5};
$scope.conditions.push(condition);
```

If you run this, you'll find that both rows have the value Question 5 selected. Looks like the model's getting confused.

Any ideas on what needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You use the old "condition"-Object twice. But you have to create a new "condition"-Object after push.

```
var condition = {};
condition.from = '';
condition.to ='';

condition.question = {title: 'Question 2', qtype: 2, _id:3};
$scope.conditions.push(condition);

condition = {}; // <= this line was added
condition.from = '';
condition.to ='';

condition.question = {title: 'Question 5', qtype: 5, _id:5};
$scope.conditions.push(condition);
```